# Emailing outlook 2007 integration

Tags: html-email, email, email-validation

I have a problem with an emailing.
I am testing on 2 different PCs, same OS, same version Outlook (2007). But for my email, I haven't same result for each Outlook...

How is it possible ? How can I have different results with the same config?

Comment: We cannot guess what the message and optics is. Two screenshots and the message source code would help if you want to get an answer. Please edit your question and add the information.

Answer (score 0):

Is one account through a work server? I had this issue with a corporate MS Exchange server removing some of the CSS from the  tag (probably for security).